# How to detect if a field will lazyload?

Tags: jpa, reflection, eclipselink

I'm trying to write some database-tests (to be run in arquillian). I need to know what fields are populated and which fields that are not populated.

So I tried with detach but unfortunally it isn't specified what is going to happend with attributes, and eclipselink chooses to keep them in a lazyloading state as long as the transactions runs (or you leave the managed context).

So, my question after a couple of fails, is it possible to detect if a field (not a list) will lazyload without leaving the managed context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at `PersistenceUtil.isLoaded(Object entity, String attributeName)` which should tell you if a field is loaded.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUtil.html